# XHR failed loading: PATCH error in Vimeo-upload.js

Tags: javascript, codeigniter-3, vimeo

I'm new to Vimeo, trying to upload videos to Vimeo using JS. Uploading seems to be working, but I'm getting  403 forbidden in the console.

PATCH https://api.vimeo.com/videos/2****9 403 (Forbidden).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `using JS` - what JS? there is no JS in the question. please see 
[how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), 
and take the 
[tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: vanilla Javascript

Comment: Did you need code?